# Rcpp setdiff function is ordering the resulting values

Tags: rcpp

It seems that the sugar Rcpp function `setdiff` orders the values, which is different from the standard R function `setdiff`.
As an example, consider the following code:

```r
src <-
"IntegerVector setdiff_Rcpp(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y){
    IntegerVector d = setdiff(x,y);
    return(d);
}"
Rcpp::cppFunction(src)

setdiff(15:11, c(13,12))
# [1] 15 14 11
setdiff_Rcpp(15:11, c(13,12))
# [1] 11 14 15
```

Is it possible to obtain a result as in the standard R function?

[Edit]
I was able to solve my problem. Here is the Rcpp function I used:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector setdiff_R(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y)
{
  // difference of sets x & y (without reordering)
  x = x[duplicated(x) == 0]; x = na_omit(x);
  y = y[duplicated(y) == 0]; y = na_omit(y);
  IntegerVector out(0, NA_INTEGER);
  for(int i=0; i < x.length(); i++)
  {
    if(is_false(any(x[i] == y)))
      out.push_back(x[i]);
  }
  return(out);
}
```

It only works for IntegerVector type and probably it is not optimised but it gets the job done.

Comment: You would need to implement this with a different hash map container.  Here the sorting is a side effect.  But the nice thing about Rcpp is that it makes it easy for _you_ to write such a new function :)

Comment: Thanks Dirk for your reply. As I'm not very fluent in C++ I guess your proposed solution is a bit outside my expertise. I hoped that setdiff was "analogous to the R version" as you wrote in your book at pag. 111.

Comment: Imagine a footnote saying _apart from the ordering_  :)

Comment: It's easy if you try, but it is hard to code :-))